# How to set elasticsearch index.mapping.total_fields.limit to unlimited

Tags: elasticsearch

I am dealing with a huge json blob so I need to open the seal. How can I set elasticsearch `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` to unlimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that current implementation allow you to set this value to unlimited.

As you probably know the default value is already high(1000) as described in [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).

And if you check the source code you can see that current implementation does not allow for unlimited(like setting to -1 for instance), as you can see in the following fragment of code taken [from official elasticsearch source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/MapperService.java):

```java
private void checkTotalFieldsLimit(long totalMappers) {
    long allowedTotalFields = indexSettings.getValue(INDEX_MAPPING_TOTAL_FIELDS_LIMIT_SETTING);
    if (allowedTotalFields < totalMappers) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Limit of total fields [" + allowedTotalFields + "] in index [" + index().getName() + "] has been exceeded");
    }
}
```

I believe your best option is to set it to a very high value when mapping your index and check if the overhead is acceptable for your use case.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot set it to unlimited. In fact, it has been intentionally limited to prevent mapping explosion. You can read the the [github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17357) here.

The only to achieve what you want is by using a high value.

You can specify that value when creating the index:

```
PUT test
{
  "shopfront": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or if it is for an existing index:

```
PUT shopfront/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

Comment: A curl command would be really helpful here.

Comment: curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
'http://elasticsearch-sc:9200/<Index_name>/_settings'  \
-d '{"index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000 }'